# Updating my IPad 3

Tags: ios, ipad

I have an IPad 3rd generation with OS 5.1.1. I want to upgrade it to iOS 6.x.

The thing is when I click on Update software on my IPad it says that the software is upto date. I get the same message in iTunes.

Can I not upgrade this IPad ?

Also I am interested to upgrade to iOS 6 instead of iOS7.

thanks.

Comment: iTunes might not let you update to iOS 6 since iOS 7 is available but I'm not certain. I am certain that you can update the iPad 3 to iOS 7 though; that's what's currently on mine.

Comment: I am guessing that since we are at iOS7 as the Newest release, the only way of getting to iOS 6 would be to go grab a IPSW from a site like this http://osxdaily.com/2012/09/19/ios-6-ipsw-direct-download-links/ and install that file using iTunes. Just backup your data first and perform the IPSW install, then restore your data backup.

Comment: See my answer here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/110585/18387

Comment: Note: only the iPad 1st gen is limited to iOS 5.1.1 - which may make this actually a mis-identification.