# Is it possible to upgrade iOS offline?

Tags: upgrade, jailbreak, ios

I have an iPad 3 iOS5.1.1 jailbroken.
Now that iOS 7 (exactly 7.0.3) is on the Apple update servers, I want to know if I am able to update my iOS to 6.1.2 or not.

I downloaded the firmware of 6.1.2 and want to update to this except iOS 7.0.3.
Anytime I want to update it via iTunes, it wants to check it with Apple servers and obviously they say you should upgrade to 7.0.3.

Is there any way I can upgrade my iOS to 6.1.2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer has been moved to a more generic question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/114076/18387

Comment: thnx for ur response. i have jailbroke my ios 5.1.1 can i now do all the things u said above and install a fresh 6.1.2 and jb it?

Comment: The blunt answer is, "No, you cannot upgrade to iOS 6.1.2." If it was an A4 device, you could save your SHSH blobs for iOS 5.1.1. You're out of luck for everything else.

Comment: tnx again then as i understood either i should go with this 5.1.1 jb or install 7.0.3 and wait for its jb? any news about this jb?

Comment: I would wait if I were you (if you can't part with your jailbreak tweaks). One of my iPhones is still on iOS 5.1.1 (jailbroken), and I use it just as much as my other iOS devices, so you can see how much I can relate to your dilemma (I have SHSH blobs coming out my ears, but I only use them on my development/testing iPod touch).