# Updating iphone 5 with ipsw file

Tags: ios, software-update

I have an iPhone 5 with iOS 6.0.1. 
Can I update with an ipsw file to iOS 6.1.2?
I don’t want to have iOS 7.

Or can I only update automatically to iOS 7?

Comment: See my answer here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/110585/18387

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/SHSH) that version of iOS ins't signed anymore by Apple. It means that you can't install that version unless you have saved the SHSH blob with softwares like TinyUmbrella. You can save SHSH blobs for certain firmware until it is signed.