# Advice on upgrading to iOS 6 from iOS 5 only

Tags: ipad, ios

I'm in need of updating the iOS on my device from 5 to 6 only (for test purposes). I already have iOS 7 on another device.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

The only option I can currently see is going to iOS 7 and then back down to 6. The problem I have is I don't want to find out it's not possible once iOS 7 is running.

Comment: See my answer here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/110585/18387

Answer (score 2):

Nope, once you update to iOS 7, you can't go back to iOS 6, since [Apple stop signing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/102929/37797) the old software when the new software is released.

You can only install versions of iOS that are currently being signed by Apple for that device.

If your device can't update to iOS 7, then it is still possible to update to iOS 6 since the latest viable version of iOS continues to be signed for those devices.

Comment: This is correct, but it doesn't really answer the main question. As in how can I only go from 5 to 6 (with an iOS 7 capable device).

Comment: @Xareyo Edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Download the iOS 6.13 software (IPSW) from http://osxdaily.com/2013/03/19/ios-6-1-3-released-with-minor-fixes-improvements/ and use iTunes to install it. Then  don't update it to 7.0 when asked .

Comment: See my answer here for why you're not entirely correct: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/110585/18387

Comment: I should note this did not work for me. The device kept crashing during the upgrade and then required an iOS 7 install to fix it.